# Bug with all-time reputation league statistics?

Tags: bug, reputation-leagues

It's nothing major, but I noticed the following in the [all-time reputation leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/2008-07-31/):

[image: screenshot1]

If you can't see the image, it shows that there have been 281,051 users that have a 1-50, 50-99, and 99-249 reputation change.

The number also shows the number 281,051 in the total reputation chart for 200-499 total reputation users.

[image: screenshot2]

It's a minor bug, but it's a bug nonetheless. Or is it just me that's seeing this?

Comment: Who's Jon Skeet?

Comment: For all we know, there *could* have been 18,349 accounts that crossed the threshold over to > 250 reputation.  But I will admit that this seems peculiar.

Comment: It's unclear what you think is a bug?

Comment: Quote: "users with less than 200 reputation ..."

Comment: @TZHX, HansPassant, I thought it was peculiar that there were exactly the same number of people (281,051) in the charts for four different categories: rep change 0+, 50+, 100+ and total rep 200+.

Comment: But because the minimum rep someone can have and be counted on that page is 200 why does this surprise you?

Comment: @TZHX That seems to make sense but then why doesn't it happen on other rep leagues, such as [this one](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow)? And even if it does, then why bother showing those repetitive statistics at all?

Comment: Because no other one has the quality of "total reputation gained" and "reputation gained in selected time period" being the same.

Comment: @TZHX Ok, got it now!